# is VPN client working one way?

Tags: centos, vpn, cisco-vpn

I have centos server and installed the VPN client(cisco-vpnclient) and able to connect to the server on the other side using private address and the server on the other side pingable using the private address .

The question

But the other side can not connect to my server using private address such as:
when the other side try to ping my server using the private ip do not get any response.

is VPN client working one way ( just send the data to VPN server and do not receive the data) ?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the configuration of both the machine which you are VPNing from as well as the VPN, but it can be setup to allow communication in both directions.

Answer (score 0):

It does depend greatly on the configuration of the vpn.  You'll want to look (with enable access) at the VPN endpoint, `show access-lists` and perhaps `show run` and see where access has been permitted too.